# Sqlalchemy scoped_session and "already attached" errors

Tags: python, multithreading, sqlalchemy

My first post here.  I'm trying to multithread a previously single threaded database application (postgresql, python2.7, sqlalchemy).

I have followed online instructions and changed my session handlers as follows. This is done in the controlling thread before launching any workers:

```
config.engine = create_engine("postgresql://foo:foobar@localhost/foo", echo=False)
config.session_factory = sessionmaker(bind=config.engine)
config.Session = scoped_session(config.session_factory)
```

The error message I get from additional threads is this. When a thread starts, it creates a new instance of the scoped session and tries to add the object (self.channel) it has received from the controlling thread to its session context:

```
self.session = config.Session()
self.session.add(self.channel)
```

The error I get from worker threads is this:

```
InvalidRequestError: Object '<YChannel at 0x7ff3bab09490>' is already attached to session '1' (this is '3')
```

What am I doing wrong? These were the errors I got when my session wasn't a scoped session, but I understood from the docs that these would go away as soon as I switched to a scoped session.

Richard

Comment: What's wrong is the fact that you're sharing objects between threads, which have different sessions. If you want to be able to do this you need to detach the instance from the old session and then re-attach it to the new session.

Comment: Ok. Then how do I solve it?  I have tables that need to be monitored and manipulated in different threads. There is a built-in mechanism to ensure different threads do not modify same objects, but storage for all threads is in the same set of tables.

Comment: You need to detach an instance from the session before you send it to another thread, and re-attach it in the receiving thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said by *universo* in comments, your are trying to share object between multiple sessions/threads. Your **channel** object is created in the main thread. When you start your executor **Thread 1** creates a new session and adds the **channel** object to it's session. Now when **Thread 2** is executed, it creates its own session and tries to add the **channel** object again to its session. Since objects cannot be shared across sessions you got an exception.

To solve this, it would really depend on what you want to achieve. If you have just one **channel** object why would you use multiple threads and sessions. If there are multiple channel objects, youe can consider creating the objects in the thread itself.